# Who created the Dailir?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

In the Lord of the Rings, the Sindarin Elf [Beleg Cúthalion](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Beleg_C%C3%BAthalion) wielded what was probably the only enchanted bow mentioned in the history of Middle-Earth (at least, the only one I could find) which he named [Belthronding](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Belthronding).

But the incredible thing about this was he used a *single* arrow, [Dailir](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Dailir) which apparently seemed to never miss its target and had a unique ability which allowed it to return to Beleg.

**Who created such an amazing arrow and why was there only one?**

And if Beleg created it, why didn't he make more as backups? (Especially since he sat on and broke the only one he had...)

Comment: It should be *a* unique ability (like '*a* unicorn,' '*a* european vacation' and 'a unicycle,' but not like '*an* umbrella'). See, for example, [A versus An](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/591/01/).

Comment: @Lexible - Gotcha! "A unique ability" does sound nicer. Thanks for mentioning that :)

Comment: Note too that the arrow seems only to have been mentioned in *The Lays of Beleriand*, not in *The Silmarillion* itself.

Comment: @MattGutting - Thanks for mentioning that, I was hoping it was mentioned in other materials such as Tolkien's letters.

Comment: Tolkien pretty much gave up on *The Lays of Beleriand* as a finished product in the late 1920s; when he went back to the basic material and stories behind it for the Annals and the Quenta, he adapted very freely, and mostly with a broad brush (so to speak).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it's not from Lord of the Rings, but from the epic poem "The Lay of the Children of Húrin", found in History of Middle-Earth series. The arrow didn't return to Beleg as such, rather, it could always be found by him.

> "Then Dailir he drew, his dart beloved;
>   howso far fared it, or fell unnoted,
>   unsought he found it with sound feathers
>   and barbs unbroken (till it broke at last)"

[...]

> "There the huntsman's hand was hurt deeply,
>   as he groped on the ground, by a gleaming point -
>   'twas Dailir his dart dearly prized
>   he had found by his foot in fragments twain,
>   and with barbs bended: it broke at last
>   neath his body falling. It boded ill."

Christopher Tolkien comments on that part of the poem:

> There is also in the poem the feature of the arrow Dailir, unfailingly found and always unharmed, until it broke when Beleg fell upon it while carrying Turin: of this there is never a mention later.

So, it seems that this magical arrow was a passing invention that wasn't given any further explanation or history.